# Send data from server to client. NodeJS, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, nodejs-express-server

I am trying to send data from my express server to the client side.

I have used app.post and app.get, the problem i'm having is that with either of those, the request must come from the client side. I need to send to push the data from the server side once a script has run has finished.

What i am doing is:

- Client inputs data on client side
- Data is send to the server using app.post api
- Server runs script
- Server sends data back to client side

Answer (score 0):

For server to client communications, look into client-side libraries such as axios or ajax.

If you are suggesting something that for example: user inputs data to form, server responds with a new page, you may be seeking a template engine. In that case, look into the Express Docs for a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

you probably looking for ejs engine. it allows you to send data from the server to the client. all you have to do is replace .html to .ejs for example: index.html will be index.ejs and you will have to add the engine in to your server as a middlware. just search about ejs